# Rails: side effect of including the same filter twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, before-filter, applicationcontroller

I have a gem I'm developing that is based around using filters on ApplicationController. It's basically for logging, and one of the modules defines an around filter like so:

```
module LogExceptionFilter
  self.included(base)
      base.around_filter :do_a_bunch_of_logging_stuff
  end

  def do_a_bunch_of_logging_stuff
      ...
  end
end
```

It happens to be an around filter where I deal with exception logging, but my question would apply for any filter.

So it's supposed to be used like this

```
class ApplicationController
    include LogExceptionFilter
end
```

So what I'm worried about is if someone does:

```
class ApplicationController
    include LogExceptionFilter
    include LogExceptionFilter
end
```

I don't want to execute `do_a_bunch_of_logging_stuff` twice. So first

1)If `do_a_bunch_of_logging_stuff` is included twice, will rails apply the filter twice?

2)Is it my responsibility to protect the user from doing this? I could do so with a class variable, something like:

```
module LogExceptionFilter

  class << self
     cattr_accessor :filter_loaded
  end

  self.included(base)
    unless filter_loaded
      base.around_filter :do_a_bunch_of_logging_stuff
      filter_loaded = true
    end
  end

  def do_a_bunch_of_logging_stuff
      ...
  end
end
```

This variable is not thread safe so it's something that I'd want to be careful about putting in. But I don't want to write a library that can be easily broken. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some relevant links:
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/95269
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/164588

Basically, a module will only be included once, but the included callback may be called multiple times.